# Error en instalacion de plantilla Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theme

Hola espero me ayuden con el siguiente error, acabo de comprar una plantilla para wordpress pero resulta que al momento de instalarla y ejecutarla la pagina se queda en un error y no carga la pagina con la plantilla instalada. Al pasar al modo debug sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method LearnPress::template() in /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-content/themes/edubee/functions.php:2111 Stack trace: #0 /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-settings.php(546): include() #1 /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-config.php(101): require_once('/home/udemaste/...') #2 /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/udemaste/...') #3 /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/udemaste/...') #4 /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-admin/customize.php(13): require_once('/home/udemaste/...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/udemaste/public_html/wp-content/themes/edubee/functions.php on line 2111
```

Comment: Hola @ProgramdorJunior, si tomas el texto del error y lo pegas en tu pregunta es más fácil poder ayudarte. Las letras en imágenes no ayudan mucho. Usa imágenes solo cuando no sea posible explicarlo en texto.

Comment: Hola @AmilcarAngeles  listo ya edite mi pregunta respecto a tu sugerencia

Comment: Hay un metodo que no existe en functions.php, en la linea 2111 se esta llamando, si fuiste tu quien lo invoco, deberias de revisar si escribiste bien el nombre al invocarlo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [ES.so], por favor lee [ask] y de paso haz el [tour], cuando se trata de temas no creados por ti lo mejor es contactar con los desarrolladores del tema pues puede haber miles de cosas que pueden fallar, sin tener el código es casi imposible ayudarte.

Comment: al parecer una función en el theme no encuentra la instancia de [learnpress](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/learnpress/) fijate si el plugin está activado, o cambia a otro theme y actualiza el theme que da problemas y el plugin si es necesario

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener activado el Plugin que requiere el tema

[LearnPress](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/learnpress/)